# .sublime-build files not present after Sublime Text 3 install

Tags: python, windows, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-build

After install of Sublime Text 2 and running a few `.py` files with <kbd>CTRL+B</kbd>, I can find this file in the filesystem:

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Python\Python.sublime-build
```

However, after installing Sublime Text 3 (portable version [from here](https://www.sublimetext.com/3)) and running a few Python files, I still can't find `Python.sublime-build` related to Sublime Text 3 in the whole filesystem.

**Have `.sublime-build` config files been packed into another file/package, and why, since it makes the editing much less handy?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have .sublime-build config files been packed into another file/package

Technically speaking, the answer to your question is no; the `Python.sublime-build` file is still in the same `Python.sublime-package` it always was, but unlike ST2, ST3 can read the contents of `sublime-package` files without extracting them first.

In ST2, Sublime performs a step called "Package Setup" whenever it starts, whereby it extracts the contents of `sublime-package` files into the `Packages` folder (when the package file has changed or when the folder version does not exist). If you check the top of the ST2 console, you can see messages regarding whether it thought it needed to do setup or not.

In ST3, Sublime can read package resources directly out of the `sublime-package` files, and so it no longer performs the package extraction step that it used to.

So, whereasin ST2 you could go to the `Packages` folder to look at the contents of a package, now you need to either peek inside of the `sublime-package` file yourself (it's just a zip file with a different extension) or use the `View Package File` command from the command palette, which will allow you to see and open any package resource from any package.

> why, since it makes the editing much less handy?

One of the main reasons for this change is to make editing package resources safer. Previously if you were to edit the extracted contents of a package, if that package ever got updated Sublime would re-extract the new package file, which could clobber your changes away.

In order to allow for packages to update without this happening, ST3 supports the idea of `overrides` for packages and resources; essentially the idea that you provide an external file and tell Sublime "Use this file instead of that one"; that way even if the `sublime-package` file changes, your changes are left intact.

This can occur in two different ways:

- If you place a `sublime-package` file in the `Installed Packages` folder and a similarly named package appears in the `Packages` folder **in the Sublime installation directory**, then the version in `Installed Packages` is used and the one that Sublime shipped with is ignored. This allows you to replace packages that ship with Sublime.
- If there is a folder in the `Packages` folder **in your user configuration area** that mimics the name of a `sublime-package` file (e.g. `Python.sublime-package` and `Python/`), then the contents of the folder are considered to be part of the `sublime-package` file, allowing you to augment the package.

  Additionally, if any files appear with the same name and relative path in the folder version, they will be used in place of the one in the `sublime-package` file (the case of the file name and path can matter in some cases, so it's best to mimic it exactly). This allows you to modify the contents of packages safely.

In both cases what this gives you is free reign to modify packages to your liking while being ensured that no matter what updates happen, your changes will remain in place. Thus it is important to note that you should ***never*** modify a `sublime-package` file (unless you're the one that made it) because when updates happen, the package file will be replaced and your updates will be lost.

The caveat here is that when `overrides` are in place, Sublime always uses them without question. So in the case that you're overriding a package file and the author also updates the package, your changed file will still be used.

The [OverrideAudit](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/OverrideAudit) package (disclaimer: I am the author) monitors when a `sublime-package` file is updated in a way that could cause your local change to be masked and warns you about it. It also contains a command for easily being able to create overrides and see how they're different from the files that they're overriding as well.

More information on how packages work in ST3 (including the various places that package files can exist) can be found in the [Demystifying Packages in Sublime Text](https://youtu.be/x6t3YdpxZfo) video.

---

### Examples of Overrides

For clarity, here are some examples of overrides using the above mechanism. In all cases we're going to use the following terms:

- `$DATA`: The location where Sublime is keeping your user specific configuration. For portable builds, this is the `Data` directory that you get when you unpack the build; in all other cases it's in a folder somewhere in your home directory. Use `Preferences > Browse Packages` and go up one folder level to find this location regardless of your OS or installation method.
- `Shipped Packages`: this is the folder named `Packages` that exists inside of the installation directory of Sublime itself (i.e. where the binary sits). This contains all of the `sublime-package` files that Sublime ships with by default.
- `Installed Packages`: This is a folder in `$DATA`. Package Control installs `sublime-package` files here and you can also place package files here manually as well. Packages contained anywhere in this folder (including subfolders) will be seen by Sublime.
- `Unpacked Packages`: This is the `Packages` folder in `$DATA` where unpacked packages are stored. `Preferences > Browse Packages` always brings you here, and it's where your `User` package is stored.

Package load order dictates that Sublime loads all of the `Shipped` packages first, then all of the `Installed` packages, and finally the `Unpacked` packages. While loading a `sublime-package` file, overrides in the `Unpacked Packages` folder are loaded as part of that phase and any remaining files are loaded later.

Within the defined order, packages are sorted lexically so that they load in order, except that `Default` is always loaded first and `User` is always loaded last. Overrides take effect at the point where Sublime would try to load a particular package or resource from that package.

#### Complete Overrides

Overrides of this type cause Sublime to wholly ignore one `sublime-package` file in favor of another; you can use this to affect changes to a package as a whole, including being able to remove files from a package which is otherwise not possible. This mechanism only applies to `Shipped` packages and is not used very often.

- Adding an empty `Python.sublime-package` (a zip file containing no files) to the `Installed Packages` folder will cause the package to appear empty, so Python support would be removed.
- Adding a version of `Python.sublime-package` to the `Installed Packages` folder that has all of the `sublime-snippet` files removed would leave Python support intact while removing all snippets.
- Adding `Sample.sublime-package` to the `Installed Packages` folder is nor an override because the `Shipped Packages` folder does not contain a package with this name. Thus this isjust a normal package installation.

#### Resource Overrides

Overrides of this type cause Sublime to favor a loose package resource file in the `Unpacked Packages` folder over a similarly named file in a `sublime-package` file (regardless of how that package is installed). This is a more common mechanism that you would use in order to adjust the content of a package file without directly modifying the `sublime-package` file itself.

- Creating a file named `$DATA/Packages/Python/Python.sublime-build` would override the same named file in `Python.sublime-package` so that as far as Sublime is concerned, that file is a part of the `sublime-package` file.
- Creating a file named `$DATA/Packages/Python/Snippets/if.sublime-snippet` would do the same thing; the name of the file in the `Python` folder has the same relative path and name as the version in the `sublime-package` file, so Sublime uses it instead.
- Creating a file named `$DATA/Packages/python/python.sublime-build` will be treated as the first example if you're on Windows or MacOS with a case-insensitive file system, but will be treated as a new package containing a new build system on Linux because the case of the file names and/or the folder don't match the `sublime-package` file name.

The determination of whether a resource is an override or not directly correlates with whether or not there is an identically named file at the correct location; anything that doesn't match that is considered as a new package or new package resource.

So for example creating `$DATA/Packages/User/Python.sublime-build` does not override the default Python build system because the default build is in the `Python` package and not the `User` package. In this case this would add a second (identically named) build system.

Since the case of the files and folders matters, it's generally best to use a package of some sort (like [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) or OverrideAudit) to create the override for you to ensure that the case of everything is correct.

Although I'm biased I generally recommend OverrideAudit for this use because PackageResourceViewer has a command to extract an entire package into the `Packages` folder. If you were to accidentally trigger that command you would effectively override the entire content of a whole package at once, which blocks it from ever updating and has the ability to cause otherwise hard to track down issues.

Comment: Thank you for the edit about overrides! So, conclusion (for portable version): 1) `/Data/Packages/User/Python.sublime-build` does *not* override the same file from inside `/Packages/Python.sublime-package`, but *adds* a new build system. 2) `/Data/Packages/Python/Python.sublime-build` does override the same file from inside `/Packages/Python.sublime-package`. Thanks for this clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Packages that ship with Sublime Text 3 are stored in special ZIP files (`*.sublime-package`) which you can find in your Sublime Text program directory (e.g. `%ProgramW6432%\Sublime Text 3\Packages`).

Apart from any unzip tool you can use the [Package Resource Viewer](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer) package to extract and edit them (see the override section in the Package Control [documentation](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/customizing_packages) for details)

The separation allows for package developers to update their packages without overwriting your customizations.

Comment: What is the benefit of having to unzip, modify, rezip, etc. (either manually or by a dedicated package/plugin) instead of just having the files normally, like in ST2? I guess it's not for the probably-500KB saved disk space. Do most users really find this handy?

Comment: I don't know, I don't care. Please do read the linked override section, there's no need to rezip.

Comment: As an FYI, the Sublime updater can and will wholesale replace `sublime-package` files on update, and Package Control does the same. So modifying packages directly will blow away your changes. Presumably the new system is in place at least so that you can modify packaged files and still have the underlying package update.

Comment: @OdatNurd Do you mean I should *not* modify content in `/Packages/thepackage.sublime-package` (which is a ZIP file)? How to override these default values then? Should I create a **new file** in `/Data/Packages/User/blahblah.sublime-build` that will override the one in the sublime-package?

Comment: @Basj When Sublime updates, it replaces package files with new ones, and Package Control does the same thing. So if you were to modify a file it would work, but at the next update your changes will go away unexpectedly. A new file named for example `Data/Packages/Python/Python.sublime-build` will override the file in the `Python.sublime-package` file; so even if the package updates, your change remains in place. For some things (like build systems) you can also create files in your `User` package as well; that doesn't override the default but it does provide a new choice to pick from.

Comment: @OdatNurd Your last comment is a perfect answer for this question, could you please post it?